# Make VLC Media Player my default player

Tags: vlc

When I insert a cd in drive, it starts up the Parole Media Player.

How do I change that so the VLC Media Player, which is installed on my PC, becomes the default player?

Comment: You may find that once vlc is set as default for audio cd's it will work but not return proper track names. If that's an issue for you comment back & I'll show how to fix.

Comment: Xubuntu.

Parole Media Player is my default player.

Instead I want VLC Media Player to be it.

I go:
Settings - Removable Drives and Media - Multimedia.

In the section Audio CDs I mark to: Play audio CDs when inserted.

And then I choose the folder icon to the right of the commandline. I choose vlc and the commandline displays: /usr/bin/vlc

Now VLC is the default player.

Comment: Thanks @doug. It actually returns proper track names at some cd's, but at some it doesn't.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Open the System-Settings. In the section "System" open "Details".
Then click on "Removeable Media" and change the "CD audio"-entry to VLC

Screenshots & more details: http://www.howtogeek.com/117709/how-to-change-your-default-applications-on-ubuntu-4-ways/

Comment: Xubuntu.

Parole Media Player is my default player.

Instead I want VLC Media Player to be it.

I go:
Settings - Removable Drives and Media - Multimedia.

In the section Audio CDs I mark to: Play audio CDs when inserted.

And then I choose the folder icon to the right of the commandline. I choose vlc, and the commandline displays: /usr/bin/vlc.
Now VLC is the default player.